# Steel surface welding with high-frequency current

Tags: steel, electromagnetism, welding, current

High-frequency currents induce skin-effect resistance that is used on some applications to weld metals.

Assume you have two steel rectangles of dimension $h_0, w, l$ and $h_1, w, l$ placed together along the $h$ axis. I'm wondering if placing a strong enough current through appropriate probes in the transverse faces of the rectangle, will generate enough heat to weld the touching faces uniformly, with no sticks or rods involved

Answer (score 1):

Look up ERW ( electric resistance welding ) , this is commonly used to weld steel pipe and tubes ( not necessarily round). Spot welding and projection welds have similar aspects.